# insert bulk data into postgresql

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert, unnest

if we want to insert the bulk data  in the PostgreSQL database by using the unnest() and if we have the data like this

```
cur.execute('''insert into table1 (col,col2,col3,....col8) values ((%s),(1),(1),('f'),('ram%s@gmail.com'),(current_date),('india'),(' '));''')
```

for this type of data how to insert data into 100000 rows

Comment: This syntax is pretty creative but has nothing to do with SQL. What is your problem?

Comment: unnest() is not supporting the current_date and special symbols .while I am using the  current date its showing the error like below

Comment: NameError: global name 'current_date' is not defined

Comment: You have to state your problem clearly, including an error message and an actual SQL statement.

Comment: actually in my code i want to insert the current_date in the some row in the table by using the unnest() here iam getting the error like **global name 'current_date' is not defined ** and the code is like that 'cur.execute(insert into table (last_modified_date) select unnest(%(last_modified_date)s) `

Comment: Please edit your question. It should contain the code you are trying to run (there is no `unnest` there) and the error message you receive. More that one line of code can help people understand the context. You should also mention (and use the tag) which programming language you are using (what's that `cur.execute`?).

Comment: Putting each value between parentheses is wrong. `values ( (1), (2) )` inserts two _rows_ with **one** column each. You need to use `values (1,2)` to insert one **row** with two **columns**